# In a batch file, how do I delete all files NOT of a certain type

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos

I'm writing a batch file that needs to delete all the files in a certain dir and all of it's subdirectories **except** those of a specific type.

How can I do this?

Comment: Or better yet, how do I copy all files of a certain type (*.java) from a dir (and all its subdirectories) while maintaining the directory structure?

Comment: Can't you just copy all the files of a certain type while maintaining directory structure with XCOPY, and then delete the rest ?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: since Monster has put the "batch" tag, I suppose he expects a scripted solution, so it is programming related.

Comment: Strongly disagree on closing for as "not programming related."

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this batch file after a coworker asked for help with deleting all the files EXCEPT for those of certain types from a folder and all subfolders, while maintaining the directory structure.  I would recommend backing up your folder before attempting this.  Just open up notepad and paste the following, save it as a .bat instead of a .txt 
Good luck!  ~Carolyn

```
REM Use at your own risk, it does a mass DELETE of everything!

SET /p ExcludeFiles=What file type should be kept (NOT deleted)? Type the file name(s) inside parantheses. example: (pdf) or (shp dbf shx)     
SET /p MapDrive=What drive letter is the folder in? example: c or n     
SET /p Directory=Drag the folder you would like to modify into this command prompt then press ENTER.     

%MapDrive%:
cd %Directory%

attrib +a *.* /s
echo %date%
for %%i in %ExcludeFiles% do attrib -a *.%%i /s
echo %date%
del %Directory%\*.* /s /a:a /q

echo %date%
attrib +a %Directory%\*.* /s
echo %date%
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something along the lines of

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (`dir /s /b *`) do if not %~xi==.txt del %i
```

For your question in the comment you can try the following:

```
robocopy source_folder target_folder *.java /s
```

or

```
xcopy *.java target_folder /s
```

which keeps the directory structure but only copies `.java` files.

Answer (score 1):

safest way is to copy all the files you do want and delete the rest.
    XCOPY *.java c:\new_directory /s

The /s copies subdirectories

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the solution found here:
[How can I delete all files/subdirs except for some files in DOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558648/how-can-i-delete-all-files-subdirs-except-for-some-files-in-dos/558662)

give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

Try researching [here](http://www.computerhope.com/delhlp.htm).

Although it doesn't give you exactly what you are asking, I would say it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ECHO DIR %address% /S /B | FIND /C %theType%>temptemp.txt
FOR /f %%a IN (temptemp.txt) DO DEL %%a
DEL temptemp.txt
```

The variable, address, is the directory and the variable, theType, is the type you do not want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
FORFILES /s /p c:\dir /c "if not @ext==.txt del /f @file"
```