# DOS batch - Print names of files (exclude certain extensions)

Tags: loops, filenames, dos

The question is about actual DOS batch files, not Windows `cmd.exe` script files.

How do I exclude files with specific extensions from being processed in a `for` loop?

```
@echo off

set myExtension=

for /r C:\ %%i in (*) do (
    ::notDesirableExtension
    if myExtension != gif or jpg
        ...
    echo myFiles >> F:\list.txt
)
```

Comment: Is your question about actual DOS (`command.com`) batch files, or about Windows command processor (`cmd.exe`) script files? There are differences in syntax and capability that are major, and the difference is important. (Your question title says both `Windows` and `DOS`.)

Comment: My question is about DOS (command.com) batch files.

Comment: I edited to indicate that, and to more clearly ask the question. Just FYI, I don't think that `::` was supported under DOS for comments; IIRC, it was only `REM` back then. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558648/how-can-i-delete-all-files-subdirs-except-for-some-files-in-dos?rq=1) might help; it's about deleting all except those with a certain extension, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks Ken but the link above did not help. I am trying to set myExtension variable in loop to extension string and then print filenames minus undesirable extensions.

Comment: Actually, it should (I wrote the accepted answer, and know what it does). In what way does it not help? You can use multiple `attrib` commands before executing the `echo`, and you haven't indicated what `myFiles` is supposed to contain. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. (The loop isn't necessary. Hide the unwanted extensions, execute `dir > F:\list.txt`, and reset the attributes to unhide the files.)

Comment: What am I trying to do?
Print all names of files in C directory minus certain files with certain extensions.

Is it possible to even set variable in loop?
I cannot get it work.
[code]
set myVar=""

for /r C:\ %%i in (*) do (

set myVar=%%i

echo myVar >> C:\list.txt
)[/code]

Comment: I've explained more than once how to do that (list the files into a text file). If you have requirements to do it a certain way (like for a homework assignment using an env. variable), please edit your question to add that requirement. Your insistence on doing it a certain way when that's not what you asked is a little frustrating. A loop is **not** required to do what your question and comments are asking, so if you have a requirement to use one specify that in your question so that people know it exists.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have access to FOR /R, it means you have access to the command extensions. So the answer is trivial.

```
@echo off
for /r C:\ %%i in (*) do (
  if "%%~xi" neq ".jpg" if "%%~xi" neq ".gif" >>F:\list.txt echo %%i
)
```

But there is no reason to use a FOR loop at all because you should also have access to FINDSTR. This FINDSTR solution should be much faster. And there is no need for a batch file. It works just fine on the command line.

```
dir /s /b /a-d-h-s | findstr /live ".jpg .gif" >F:\list.txt
```

Command extensions were not introduced until Windows 2000, which is not true DOS.

Comment: It looks like you should escape the dot in search criteria with \  symbol like this          findstr /live "\.jpg \.gif"            or it will be finding files like this for expample "asa_jpgd.doc" ,    by the way  - what /live switch means?

Comment: @qwebek - `/LIVE` is short for `/L /I /V /E` which is "Literal", "Ignore case", "inVerse", "match End of line". Since it is a literal search, not regex, and since it must match the end of line, then the dot does not need to be escaped, and it will only match the correct extensions.