# Delete all files in folder except file in list using batch

Tags: windows, string, batch-file

I have three file in a folder (temp folder) that are

```
1.txt
2.exe
3.txt
```

Now I will use to batch to write script for deleting all files in the folder except one file (3.txt). How to write it in script. I try to use

```
del temp /Q
```

But it will delete all file in my folder. I don't want to delete all. I only want to delete 1.txt and 2.exe. Let consider number of file is large.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the command

```
except 3.txt del temp /Q
```

It will delete all files in the folder except 3.txt

Comment: What version of batch / Windows command prompt are you using?  I've never seen "except", and I have an error thrown when I try this. Further, this syntax looks very strange for batch in general...

Comment: I think you have to add this batch on the path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/558677/1952213

Answer (score 2):

If you loop through the contents of a directory, you can apply whatever logic you might want, and perform whatever operations you might want on those contents.  Example:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set dirPath=C:\Users\BuvinJ\Desktop\test

pushd !dirPath!

:: Loop through all files in this directory 
for %%a in (*) do (
    set fileName=%%a
    if "!fileName!"=="1.txt" (
        echo FOUND: !fileName!
    ) else (
        echo OTHER: !fileName!
    )
)

:: Loop through all sub directories in this directory
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    set dirName=%%a
    echo Directory: !dirName!
)

popd
```

You might also want to step through the contents "recursively", i.e. drilling down into the nested sub directories. To do so add /r after your for statement (like with the /d in the example to loop through directories instead of files).

For more on this kind of looping, check this out: http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html