# How delete all files and folders in a directory respectively an entire directory tree except files specified in a list file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am wondering how I can solve the following with a batch file.

Delete all files and folders inside `G:\AD\mods` except for a list of all files and folders I want to keep.

Has anyone some suggestions for a batch file solution?

I have tried the following Windows command line in a batch file:

```
for %%i in (*.*) do if not "%%i"=="doc1.txt" if not "%%i"=="doc2.txt" del /q "%%i"
```

This works, but I was only able to delete files from the same folder as the batch file was placed in.

Then I read this post: [Delete all files in folder except file in list using batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077336/delete-all-files-in-folder-except-file-in-list-using-batch)

It suggests something like:

```
except 3.txt del temp /Q
```

This also works in the same folder, but not for files and folders in different levels of the directory tree.

**EDIT:**

I have a main folder with about 1000 sub folders. These folders also have sub folders in them. The same file name might be present in multiple folders. So I need to specify the exact file path for each file I want to keep.

Example for the names in the list file of the files to keep:

```
AD\mods\folder1\doc1.txt
AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\doc1.txt
AD\mods\folder2\doc1.txt
```

All other files should be removed by the batch file.

A PowerShell solution would be also okay.

Comment: By the way: take a look at [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), which features `/XF` and `/XD` options to exclude files and directories, resp.; together with the `/E` and `/MOVE` options, you could simply move all but the exclusion items to a temporary directory and eventually remove that one then…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume the list file `G:\AD\mods\Exclusion List.txt` contains only file/folder names without path like:

```
Cleanup.cmd
Exclusion List.txt
Folder to keep
File not to delete.txt
```

The batch file `G:\AD\mods\Cleanup.cmd` can be used with the following command lines to delete all files and folders in directory of the batch file with exception of the files and folders in exclusion list file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderPath=%~dp0"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%FolderPath%" /AD /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /G:"%FolderPath%Exclusion List.txt"') do rd /Q /S "%FolderPath%%%I"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%FolderPath%" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /G:"%FolderPath%Exclusion List.txt"') do del /A /F "%FolderPath%%%I"
endlocal
```

The first **FOR** command line runs with using a separate command process started in background the command **DIR** to output all folder names in directory of the batch file filtered with **FINDSTR** to exclude from the folder names list all folder names listed in the exclusion list file. The resulting list is processed by **FOR** which runs command **RD** to delete these folders.

The second **FOR** command line runs with using a separate command process started in background the command **DIR** to output all file names in directory of the batch file filtered with **FINDSTR** to exclude from the file names list all file names listed in the exclusion list file. The resulting list is processed by **FOR** which runs command **DEL** to delete these files.

The **FOR** option `eol=|` is used to avoid ignoring file/folder names starting with a semicolon as no file/folder name can contain a vertical bar. The **FOR** option `delims=` defines an empty list of string delimiters resulting in turning off the default behavior of `for /F` to split the captured lines into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assign only the first space/tab separated string to the specified loop variable `I`. That option is necessary to correct process also file/folder names with one or more spaces.

---

The task requirements changed to delete all files in entire directory tree except the files listed in an exclusion list file with path (without drive letter and colon).

So let us assume the file `G:\AD\mods\Exclusion List.txt` contains the following lines.

```
G:\AD\mods\Cleanup.cmd
G:\AD\mods\Exclusion List.txt
AD\mods\folder1\doc1.txt
AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\doc1.txt
AD\mods\folder2\doc1.txt
```

The batch file `G:\AD\mods\Cleanup.cmd` can be used with the following command lines to delete first all files in entire directory tree of the directory containing the batch file and the exclusion list file with exception of the files in the exclusion list file and next delete all directories recursively which do not contain anymore at least one file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderPath=%~dp0"
if "%FolderPath:~-1%" == "\" set "FolderPath=%FolderPath:~0,-1%"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%FolderPath%" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /G:"%FolderPath%\Exclusion List.txt"') do del /A /F "%%I"
call :DeleteEmptyFolders "%FolderPath%"
goto EndBatch

:DeleteEmptyFolders
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir %1 /AD /B 2^>nul') do call :DeleteEmptyFolders "%~1\%%I"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir %1 /A /B 2^>nul') do goto :EOF
rd /Q /S %1
goto :EOF

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Please note that the **FINDSTR** option `/X` is replaced in first **FOR** command line by the option `/E` to filter out all file names of which full qualified name just **ends** with one of the strings in the exclusion list file instead of matching the entire file name because of the list file contains the file names without drive letter and colon. That could result in a wrong filtering depending on which part of the full path of a file is in the list file.

So what happens with this batch file on following directory tree on drive `G:`:

- **AD**

  - **backups**

    - **folder1**

      - **subfolder1**

        - ;File to keep.txt
        - doc1.txt
      - doc1.txt
  - **mods**

    - **folder1**

      - **subfolder1**

        - ;File to delete.txt
        - *doc1.txt*
      - *doc1.txt*
      - One More File!.txt
    - **folder2**

      - **Empty subfolder 1**
      - **Subfolder 2**

        - **Another Empty Folder**
        - doc1.txt
      - *doc1.txt*
      - Log file in folder2().log
    - **folder3**

      - doc1.txt
    - *Cleanup.cmd*
    - *Exclusion List.txt*
    - Readme.txt

The result of the execution of `G:\AD\mods\Cleanup.cmd` is:

- **AD**

  - **backups**

    - **folder1**

      - **subfolder1**

        - ;File to keep.txt
        - doc1.txt
      - doc1.txt
  - **mods**

    - **folder1**

      - **subfolder1**

        - *doc1.txt*
      - *doc1.txt*
    - **folder2**

      - *doc1.txt*
    - *Cleanup.cmd*
    - *Exclusion List.txt*

So everything in `G:\AD\backups` is kept and in `G:\AD\mods` only the folders with files of which names are listed in the exclusion list file remain and all other files and folders are deleted by the batch script.

The directories and files can be created with following batch code with exception of `Cleanup.cmd` and `Exclusion List.txt` in `G:\AD\mods`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BasePath=G:"
md "%BasePath%\AD\backups\folder1\subfolder1" 2>nul
md "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1" 2>nul
md "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder2\Empty subfolder 1" 2>nul
md "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder2\Subfolder 2\Another Empty Folder" 2>nul
md "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder3" 2>nul
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !BasePath!\AD\backups\folder1\subfolder1\;File to keep.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\backups\folder1\subfolder1\;File to keep.txt"
echo !BasePath!\AD\backups\folder1\subfolder1\doc1.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\backups\folder1\subfolder1\doc1.txt"
echo !BasePath!\AD\backups\folder1\doc1.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\backups\folder1\doc1.txt"
(echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\;File to delete.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\;File to delete.txt") 2>nul
echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\doc1.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\doc1.txt"
echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\doc1.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\doc1.txt"
echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\One More File^^!.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder1\One More File^!.txt"
(echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder2\Subfolder 2\doc1.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder2\Subfolder 2\doc1.txt") 2>nul
echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder2\doc1.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder2\doc1.txt"
echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder2\Log file in folder2().log>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder2\Log file in folder2().log"
echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\folder3\doc1.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\folder3\doc1.txt"
echo !BasePath!\AD\mods\Readme.txt>"!BasePath!\AD\mods\Readme.txt"
endlocal
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +r "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\;File to delete.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +h "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder2\Subfolder 2\doc1.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +h "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder2\Empty subfolder 1"
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +r +s +h "%BasePath%\AD\mods\folder3"
endlocal
```

The deletion of the folder `G:\AD\mods\folder3` is tricky as it has the read-only attribute set (and the system and hidden attribute) which results in the error message `Access is denied.` on using the command `rd %1 2>nul` after the first **FOR** loop in subroutine `DeleteEmptyFolders` which would otherwise delete only empty folders. For that reason a second **FOR** loop is used running once again **DIR** in a separate command process in background. The subroutine is exited if the directory is not empty because of still containing a file or a folder. Otherwise the folder is empty and `rd /Q /S %1` is used to delete the empty folder even on having the read-only attribute set.

---

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file path always ending with a backslash.
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on the **FOR** command lines to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes the command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the embedded command line appended as additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has a command for you.

```
Remove-Item -Path 'C:\src\delt\*' -Exclude 't.txt','x.txt'
```

If you have a file containing a list of files to exclude from removal:

```
Remove-Item -Path 'delt\*' -Exclude (Get-Content -Path '.\deltexclude.txt')
```

If you must run it from cmd.exe or a .bat file script:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Remove-Item -Path 'C:\src\delt\*' -Exclude 't.txt','x.txt'"
```

Read about the `Remove-Item` command using:

In a PowerShell console:

```
help Remove-Item -Full
```

In a cmd.exe console:

```
powershell "help Remove-Item -Full"
```

Comment: PowerShell is also ok. I tested, and I got it working. But can I do it more broad?

Something like "Delete everything from \mods\*" except "list of full path names to files I want to keep"?
I tried the following with with no success:
-Exclude: "AD\mods\folder1\subfolder1\doc1.txt", "AD\mods\folder2\doc1.txt"

Comment: @JensPetterRøyseth, you are expanding the requirements of this question.