# keep files which names are in text file and delete the rest in folder CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

how to make this batch code to keep the files in the list.txt and delete the rest in folder?
I hope its clear enough so basically just what should be done to change keep files mentioned in text file and delete the rest that are not in the text file
the below is to DELETE files mentioned in the text files i want the opposite

```
@echo off
REM Delete files/folders specified in a newline delimited txt file list. 
 
set "default_list_path=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ListOfFilesToKEEP.txt"
 
if not "%~2"=="" echo Error: unexpected arguments& exit /b
if not "%~1"=="" ( set "list=%1" ) else (
    set "list=%DEFAULT_LIST_PATH%"
)
 
if not exist "%LIST:"=%" echo Error: list could not be found& exit /b
 
set /a delete_counter=0
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('type "%LIST:"=%"') do (
    if exist "%%~fI" (
        set /a delete_counter+=1
        if exist "%%~fI"\* (
            rd /s /q "%%~fI"
        ) else (
            del /q "%%~fI"
        )
    ) else (
        echo No such path "%%~I".
    )
)
 
echo.& echo %DELETE_COUNTER% files or folders were deleted.
```

Comment: That can be done with `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /G:"%list%"') do if exist "%%I\" (rd /Q /S "%%I") else del /A /F "%%I"`. Run in a command prompt window `del /?`, `dir /?`, `findstr /?`, `for /?`, `if /?` and `rd /?` to get output the usage help of each used [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) explaining the used options. The batch file should not be in current directory or its file name is also in the list file.

Comment: See also: [How delete all files and folders in a directory respectively an entire directory tree except files specified in a list file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054336/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the following way (note the file paths):

```
cd <PathToFolder> ;Insert this line if the batch file is not in the desired folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /i /v /g:<path>list.txt') do del "%%f"
```

Comment: the batch file just disappear no errors nothing