# Batch to remove all files in folder + subfolder except some filetypes

Tags: batch-file, file-extension, subdirectory

I have a folder with thousand of subfolders.
There are many files like .cfg's or .txt's, that are unnecessary.

I only need the folders with files that contain .png and .jpg .
So the procedure should be:

- Find all files except .png and .jpg files and delete them
- Check all empty folders and delete them

I found the following code:

[How can I delete all files/subdirs except for some files in DOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558648/how-can-i-delete-all-files-subdirs-except-for-some-files-in-dos/558662)

If I want to add .png AND .jpg, what do I have to add?

```
attrib +r +s *.png
attrib +r +s *.jpg
del *.*
attrib -r -s *.bat
attrib -r -s *.jpg
```

doesn't seem to work. Also I need the folder-remover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the solution myself in the end.

```
REM Use at your own risk, it does a mass DELETE of everything!

SET ExcludeFiles=(png jpg)     
SET MapDrive=%cd:~0,1%
SET Directory=%~dp0

%MapDrive%:
cd %Directory%

attrib +a *.* /s
echo %date%
for %%i in %ExcludeFiles% do attrib -a *.%%i /s
echo %date%
del %Directory%\*.* /s /a:a /q

echo %date%
attrib +a %Directory%\*.* /s
echo %date%

for /f "usebackq" %%d in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set the_dir=c:\dir_with_images
pushd "%the_dir%"

:: delete files that are not pictures
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /s /a:-d|findstr /i /v ".jpg .png"') do (
 rem -- remove "ECHO" bellow if everything is OK 
 ECHO del /q /f "%%~f#" 
)

:: delete empty folders
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /s /a:d|findstr /i /v ".jpg .png"') do (
  :: recursively deletes empty folders .Without /S switch RD should not delete non-empty folders
  RD "%%~f#" >nul 2>nul
)
```

Not tested .YOu should set your path at the beginning. Deleting files is not 'activated' - only an echoing .You should delete the `ECHO` as its mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, neither it does echo anything nor does it delete anything after deleting the echo-comment.